# Can i get a single field from php to android without using json?

Tags: php, android, mysql

i am trying to get a single field from mySql through php and use it in my android app.. how can i get a single field from php to android without using json? im trying to set a radiobutton's text into the field i get? here's my php code:

```
    <?php
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass123");
   if (!$con)
     {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

   mysql_select_db("voting", $con);

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM ssc_president WHERE Party = '123'")
   or die(mysql_error());
   $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

   $pname = $row['Name'];
   //echo "Name: ".$row['Name'];

   mysql_close($con);
   ?>
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_query` in new code. It's horribly insecure by default and leads to nothing but pain and suffering when you make a mistake that ends up with your site being exploited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XML` to get single name from server other than that You will have to hard code text of `radio button` in `android`.

To get dynamic data from server you need to call `webservice` which give data either in `XML` or `JSON`. Its depend on which you  are using.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP, simply echo the field you want.  Make sure that is all you print.

```
<?php
...
echo $mydata;

?>
```

And from Android, read it with an `HttpClient`

```
String result = "";
InputStream is=null;
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("MyURLGoesHERE");      
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
    }
    is.close();
}catch(Exception ex){  
    Log.e("Error",ex.toString());
}


Log.d("DataFromPHP",result);
```